# Rebasing a remote (master) branch to a specific commit

Tags: git, github, rebase

I accidentally pushed `local:deploy` branch commits to `remote:master` branch.

I know the last commit on remote master branch because I also have a local Master intact on this specific commit. Hence, I want to revert this incidence and set remote master to that specific commit. one way is to pull changes from remote master to local master and then remove commits of  `local:deploy`. I am afraid to make thing worse again. Please advise.

I use git for minimal operations ( git clone, add, push, pull) and does not have advance knowledge of rebase, cherry-pick etc.

Please advise on how to revert this incident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the remote to have the same commits as the local copy on the `master` branch, and you are **absolutely sure about this**, then you can forcefully push your local `master` to replace the remote's copy.

So, if your remote is named `origin`, the commands to do this would be:

```
git checkout master
git push --force origin master
```

This cannot be undone, so make absolutely sure this is what you want to do. If you have any doubts at all, clone the remote to another directory before doing this, just in case.

Comment: things seem to be normal now. I hope it won't break other actions in future. anyway. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: And for newbies like me and future references, please make sure that you know exactly what you are doing. this solution helped me since this repository is being managed by ME ONLY, not a production code and there are NO other collaborator or contributor. I even have another OS environment and I also use that too. In that case, I might have changes committed to master in that system and not updated here. So, I made sure that the `local copy of master` is same across both of my systems.